# Converting dplyr chain to function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse

Hi so I am just trying to figure out how to convert a dplyr chain into a function in R. So the position and speed variables have three potential values. For position: "rb", "wr", "te". For speed it's: "fast", "medium", "slow". The head of my table looks like this:

```r
position       speed          yards 
   rb          fast            805                 
   wr          slow            924                 
   rb          medium          503 
   te          fast            803 
   wr          medium          1002 
   rb          fast            920   
   te          slow            530  
   rb          fast            920  
   wr          slow            920
```

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to find the proportion of speed (for example medium) out of a positions' total yards. I know how to do it in dplyr. This gives me the correct answer:

```r
df %>%    
  group_by(position, speed) %>%
  summarise(yards = sum(yards)) %>%
  group_by(position) %>%
  mutate(freq = yards / sum(yards))
```

```r
  position speed  yards  freq
1 rb       fast    1729 0.200
2 rb       medium  4741 0.547
3 rb       slow    2196 0.253
```

Is there anyway I can put this into a function where I can input the position and the speed and get the correct proportion? When I mean I want to input the position or speed, I mean being able to just put in for example "wr" and "medium" into a function and getting the proportion of yards by medium speed players at position "wr". Thank you

Comment: Can you please spell out a bit more what you'd like "input the position and the speed and get the correct proportion" to look like? [Please edit the question to add this.]

Comment: FYI, your summary statistics do not reflect what this sample data provides.

Comment: Hi. So the position and speed variables have three potential values. For position: "rb", "wr", "te". For speed it's: "fast", "medium", "slow". When I mean I want to input the position or speed, I mean being able to just put in for example "wr" and "medium" into a function and getting the proportion of yards by medium speed players at position "wr"

Comment: @r2evans correct. That isn't the full table above. Just part of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
lookup_func <- function(homeworld, species) {

  # You could keep this part outside of the function if you just want to calc once
  my_lookup_table <- dplyr::starwars %>%
    group_by(homeworld, species) %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean), .groups = "drop")
  
  # Here we filter using the input text and the "curly curly" or "embrace" operator
  #   in "tidyeval" that serves to transport the input into
  #   the context of the function.
  my_lookup_table %>%
    filter(homeworld == {{ homeworld }},
           species   == {{ species }})
}
```

Try it out:

```
lookup_func("Tatooine", "Human")

# A tibble: 1 x 5
  homeworld species height  mass birth_year
  <chr>     <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Tatooine  Human     179.    NA       47.5
```

For more on the "curly curly" operator, I suggest looking at https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/  and https://sharla.party/post/tidyeval/